# London to Colombo via Mumbai - transit visa needed?

Tags: visas, india, transit-visas, uk-citizens, connecting-flights

I have got an e-ticket for the flight. It's Jet Airways, London to Colombo with a 7.5 hour connection in Mumbai. Same operator (Jet Airways). Do I need a transit visa? [EDIT: Is this the correct restatement of facts?]

Comment: I have re-edited the question to conform to a chronological statement of flights (correctly?), but in any event we need to know your citizenship, and possibly your visa status if you are an expatriate, to answer.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Irrelevant. Unless OP only has a document for stateless people or refugees, **and** if the trip is in a single booking, no visa is required

Comment: @Crazydre Irrelevant for that airport, could have mattered for another.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Applies to all Indian Airports with international interline connections

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the trip is in one booking, **no**, you do not need a transit visa.

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IN&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines, says:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours
>
> Not applicable to stateless persons and refugees.

So unless you're a refugee or stateless, you'll be fine.